# JTree set node name as one of UserObject attribute

Tags: java, swing, jtree, nodename, user-object

I'm using JTree to create tree view and add node to its root as following:

```
String nodeName = "node1";
DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeName);
root.add(child);
```

The `UserObject` for each node now has type of `String`. It shows `"node1"` as node name when display the tree.

However, I want to add `UserObject` to the node as an Object of the `nodeObject` class with 2 attributes:

```
private class nodeObject{
    private String nodeName;
    private boolean isSomethingElse;
    public nodeObject(String name, boolean something){
       nodeName = name;
       isSomethingElse = something;
    }
    public String getName(){
       return nodeName;
    }
    //Other setter/getter after these code
}
```

When I add this nodeObject to tree node:

```
nodeObject nodeObject = new nodeObject("node1",true);
DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeObject);
root.add(child);
```

It shows the `object ID` as node name.
My question is, how i can set the node name as `nodeObject.getName()` so the tree can show `"node1"` as node name?

Any reply is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I found out solution by writing my own TreeNode that extends DefaultMutableTreeNode, then overwrite toString() function.

Answer (score 5):

If this object is dedicated to the JTree, and is not used anywhere else, the easiest way is to override the `toString()` method and return the name from this method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nodeName;
}
```

If you want a different toString() method, that could be used to provide more information when debugging for example, then set a custom `TreeCellRenderer` to the tree. This custom could just extend DefaultTreeCellRenderer, and override the following method:

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
                                              Object value,
                                              boolean sel,
                                              boolean expanded,
                                              boolean leaf,
                                              int row,
                                              boolean hasFocus) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
    NodeObject nodeObject = (NodeObject) node.getUserObject();
    return super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,
                                              nodeObject.getName(),
                                              sel,
                                              expanded,
                                              leaf,
                                              row,
                                              hasFocus);
}
```

EDIT:

A third solution, as mentioned by aterai in the comments, is to subclass JTree and to override the `convertValueToText()` method, that the default renderer calls. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html for more details about trees.

Comment: or override 'JTree#convertValueToText(...)': http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html > Sometimes, it is not feasible to override toString; in such a scenario you can override the convertValueToText of JTree to map the object from the model into a string that gets displayed.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for pointing me to this method, that I didn't know. I'll edit my answer.